# how to preserve quotes when referencing a value using placeholders in a YAML file with Spring Cloud Config?

Tags: spring, encryption, spring-cloud-config

I have a password ending in a colon, say `abc:`, that I want to store encrypted in GIT and decrypt with Spring Cloud Config.
Here's the expected YAML file :

```
spring:
  datasource:
    password: "abc:"
```

Here's the encrypted YAML file :

```
spring:
  datasource:
    password: "{cipher}blablabla"
```

And here's what I receive from Spring Cloud Config after decryption :

```
spring:
  datasource:
    password: abc:
```

Which is interpreted as a key instead of a value by the YAML parser.

Is there a way to tell Spring Cloud Config that I want to surround the decrypted value in quotes or something similar ?

**EDIT**

My mistake, Spring Could Config server actually adds quotes when needed after decrypting the string. So the result is as expected :

```
spring:
  datasource:
    password: 'abc:'
```

The issue is that when I reference this value using a placeholder the quotes disappear in the process :

```
a_key:
  another_key: ${spring.datasource.password}
```

becomes when processed by Spring Could Config server :

```
a_key:
  another_key: abc:
```

So the question really is : how to preserve quotes when referencing a value using placeholders in a YAML file with Spring Cloud Config?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found so far is to leave the placeholder resolution to runtime by escaping the `$` character :

```
a_key:
  another_key: \${spring.datasource.password}
```

The resulting YAML served by Spring Cloud Config server is then :

```
a_key:
  another_key: ${spring.datasource.password}
```

Link to Spring Cloud Config documentation [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.4.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_property_overrides)